# Java: JAXB and using char

Tags: java, jaxb, char, primitive, java-metro-framework

I'm working on a project with JAXB but I run into a small problem with JAXB and the char datatype.

```
char gender = 'M';
```

Translates after marshalling into:

```
<gender>77</gender>
```

So I think that char is mapped to integer, but I simply want to map it to a String. How can I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Don't store gender as a char and use an `enum` instead. Not only is it a lot more type-safe but you can also map it however you want ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: You are right with with saying enum would be a beter option to  store the gender. But I'm exploring the possibilities of JAXB. And I'm stubborn so I just figured there must be a solution of using char :-p

Comment: This is a bug in one particular implementation of JAXB (Metro), other implementations of JAXB (EclipseLink MOXy) marshal char correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some experimentation, there appears to be no way to configure JAXB to handle primitive chars properly. I'm having a hard time accepting it, though.

I've tried defining an `XmlAdaptor` to try and coerce it into a String, but the runtime seems to only accept adapters annotated on Object types, not primitives.

The only workaround I can think of is to mark the char field with `@XmlTransient`, and then write getters and setters which get and set the value as a String:

```
   @XmlTransient
   char gender = 'M';

   @XmlElement(name="gender")
   public void setGenderAsString(String gender) {
      this.gender = gender.charAt(0);
   }

   public String getGenderAsString() {
      return String.valueOf(gender);
   }
```

Not very nice, I'll grant you, but short of actually changing your char field tobe a String, that's all I have.

Comment: This issue is related specifically to the Metro implementation of JAXB, other implementations of JAXB (EclipseLink MOXy) handle this use case correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyAdapter.class, type=int.class)
```

Thats the trick specify type to make it work with primitives

In your adapter

using the same in package-info will mean you do it globally for that package

Found this after experimenting.

```
public class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Integer> {
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing i got in my mind :)

```
String gender = "M";
```

Answer (score 1):

This still appears to be a problem in Metro JAXB (the RI), atleast the version of Metro shipped with JDK 1.6.0_20.

EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) marshals char correctly:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php

To use EclipseLink JAXB simply add eclipselink.jar to your classpath and add a jaxb.properties file in with your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

create a specialized XmlAdapter:

```
package br.com.maritima.util;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class CharAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,Character>{

 @Override
 public String marshal(Character v) throws Exception {
  return new String(new char[]{v});
 }

 @Override
 public Character unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
   if(v.length()>0)
   return v.charAt(0);
  else return ' ';
 }

}
```

then you can register it to entire package with package-info.java (avoid to forgot it inside some other class) or use it specifically for a certain field.

see http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/exchanging_data_with_xml_and
for more info.

Comment: I'm curious, why do `new String(new char[]{v})` instead of `v.toString()`?